# Time Based Events in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, workflow-foundation

I need to perform some events (sending emails, etc.) based on time.  What is the best way to accomplish this in ASP.net in a hosted (medium trust) environment?

ex:  Send email every day at 4:00pm.
ex:  Send email after 15min of login.
ex:  Send email after 10 hrs of last change to status.

The triggering logic can be complex on some of the requirements, so I need to build a flexible system to handle these sorts of events.  I am stuck on the core activation method for this code.

Here are the options I have so far...

**1) Timer in Global.asax**
   + Simple
   - Is not reliable, the web application can unload in IIS and the event will not fire.
   ? Possibly use external pinger service to keep app alive (reliable?)

**2) Windows Service to perform action**
   - Slip/Maintain separate code.
   - Can not install in hosted environment (shared/cloud hosting)

**3) Windows Service to call Web App (calls webservice or runs page)**
   + All code in web app
   - Can not install in hosted environment.

**4) SQL Server Job to call a Webservice (via CLR)**
   ? Haven't looked at this.. possible? reliable in hosted environment?

**5) SQL Service Broker Timer to add message to call WebService (via CLR)**
   ? Haven't looked at this.. possible? reliable in hosted environment?

**6) Windows Workflow?**
   ? No Idea.. does this technology have anything for this?

This seems like a common enough problem, are there third party tools to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, and I agree totally with your analysis. My best solution to date is having an external scheduling application in a computer I control; that application requests the web page that actually does the things.

Ugly but it works, and I have searched for other solutions, believe me!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using SQL Server Jobs.

It has all schedules that are required in your solution, also it's very reliable and can be extended with C# code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to to set up a scheduled task in Windows, running a simple console app or batch file. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task

Trying to do what yo're talking about in IIS has problems. Read Phil Haack's post on [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [quartz scheduler](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) it does job scheduling. It is a.Net port of the java version.  See this getting started article http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/04/10/walkthrough-scheduling-jobs-using-quartz.net-ndash-part-1-what-is.aspx.

We also use Azure and use workers roles for scheduled tasks. You can see this article here on building basic scheduled tasks with Azure work roles http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-a-task-scheduler-in-windows-azure

In the past we have also set up web page that calls the task and used a service like https://www.pingdom.com/ to call the page on a scheduled basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use ASP.NET, then I would use a combination of SQL Server, WCF, and ASP.NET caching to do your scheduled tasks. You can easily modify it to do shorter or longer intervals (e.g. hourly or weekly) This one will only do daily tasks at a selected time.

### 1. Setup a SQL Table for Your Tasks

> ```
> Column Name        Data Type   
> Id                 int
> Name               varchar(100) 
> LastRun            datetime
> Interval           int 
> RunTime            datetime
> ```

### 2. Add Some Data to the Table

> ```
> 1 
> My Daily Email Task 
> 08/15/08 (old date)
> 300 (5 minutes)
> 09:00
> ```

The interval basically tells the server how often to check the time. The shorter the time, the more accurate the runtime will be with the cost of having to check the database more often.

### 3. If using an ORM, Create a Class Mapping

```
public class Task
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? LastRun { get; set; }

    public virtual int Interval { get; set; }

    public virtual TimeSpan? RunTime { get; set; }
}
```

This uses fluent nhibernate. Entity Framework works great too.

### 4. Create Service Calls to Get/Save the Tasks

```
public Task[] GetTasks()
{

    var main = new Application.Main();
    using (var sessionFactory = main.SessionFactory)
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Query<Task>().ToArray();
    }

}

public bool SaveTask(Task task)
{
    var main = new Application.Main();
    using (var sessionFactory = main.SessionFactory)
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.SaveOrUpdate(task);
        trans.Commit();

        return trans.WasCommitted;
    }
}
```

This uses WCF for the service calls. Technically, you don't need a web service, but I think it helps with organization when you keep your database queries separate from your ASP.NET site.

### 5. Setup the scheduling in your global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var service = new MyService.MyServiceClient();
    var tasks = service.GetTasks();

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        AddTask(task);
    }

    service.Close();
}
```

The above function basically grabs all the tasks and puts it through a caching cycle.

```
private void AddTask(PortalService.Task task)
{
        var onCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(task.Name, task, null,
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(task.Interval), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, onCacheRemove);
}
```

The above function adds each task in the database to the ASP.NET runtime cache that loops through based on the interval you specified in the database.

```
public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object taskObj, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    var task = (MyService.Task)taskObj;



    //Run the task if it is the next day and greater than or equal to the runtime
    if (task.LastRun.HasValue && task.LastRun.Value.Day != DateTime.Now.Day && task.RunTime.HasValue && task.RunTime.Value.Hours <= DateTime.Now.Hour && task.RunTime.Value.Minutes <= DateTime.Now.Minute))
    {
        RunTask(ref task);
    }


    //Add the task again so that this method gets called again
    AddTask(task);
}
```

When our interval expires the above function is called that runs our task.

### 6. Create the Function that Runs your Various Tasks' Logic

```
        private void RunTask(ref PortalService.Task task)
        {

            var service = new MyService.MyServiceClient();

            switch (task.Name)
            {
                case "My Daily Email Task":
                    service.SendDailyEmail();
                    break;
                case "Another Daily Task":
                    service.DoAnotherOperation();
                    break;
                case "Yet Another Daily Task":
                    service.DoYetAnotherOperation();
                    break;
            }

            //Update the task to indicate that it ran
            task.LastRun = DateTime.Now;
            service.SaveTask(task);


            service.Close();
        }
```

Overall, this solutions works decently, given the many improvements that can be made upon it. App pool recycling shouldn't affect this solution if you have your interval set fairly low since the last run state is stored in the database.